# Gulp Nunjucks: Case insensitiv include?

Tags: gulp, nunjucks

I have a large project built on windows which uses loads of includes written in uppercase
`{% include 'TEMPLATE.html' %}`
but the files are named in lowercase `template.html`
Now the project won't build on Linux ... Is there a way to fix this in the gulpfile nunjucks.compile()?
Thanks

Comment: `{% include 'TEMPLATE.html' | lower %}`? :D

Comment: Thanks @AikonMogwai - my goal is to not change a huge number of templates so I was thinking to do it in the gulpfile

Comment: Any solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

If gulp doesn't have the required option, you can use a custom loader or override `include`-tag.

Template `test.html`: `TEST - {{result or 'Failed'}}`

```
const nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
const fileLoader = new nunjucks.FileSystemLoader('views') 
const MyLoader = nunjucks.Loader.extend({
    getSource: path => fileLoader.getSource(path.toLowerCase())
});

const env = new nunjucks.Environment(new MyLoader(), {autoescape: true});
const html = env.render('TEST.html', {result: 'OK'});
console.log(html);
```